# Command prompt gives different output than git bash

Tags: git, bash, batch-file, jenkins, cmd

So I am trying to execute a batch script in Jenkins:

```
for /f %%i in ('git rev-list --count %BRANCH_NAME% ^^%MERGE_TO%') do set commits=%%i
```

where %BRANCH_NAME% and %MERGE_TO% are passed in to the Jenkins job.  When it executes, this is the output:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Merge\workspace>for /F %i in ('git rev-list --count branch ^mrgbld') do set commits=%i 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Merge\workspace>set commits=2305
```

The command should return 5, not 2305.  It turns out that if you run that command in git bash, you get 5, but running it in the windows command prompt (where Jenkins executes the command) gives 2305.

I am looking either for a way to trick Jenkins into running the command in git bash, or to make the windows command prompt give the same output.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a different form of the git command fixes the issue:

```
git rev-list --count %MERGE_TO%..%BRANCH_NAME%
```

This returns the proper number of commits, whether run in git or windows command